# save foreign key object django forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am facing a problem and I am unable to solve it on my on so I need your help.
I am saving profile object using django form and its working perfectly fine on my local system but when I deploy it on server it gives me an error saying:

> Cannot assign "'demo'": "Profile.company" must be a "Company" instance.

demo is company name i am getting from frontend

Model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      company = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Form.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
company = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            "placeholder": "Company",
            "class": "form-control"
        }
    ))

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ('company',)
```

Views.py

```
 company = Company.objects.filter(company_name=request.POST["company"]).first()
 form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
 p_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
 if form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
     u_user = form.save()
     p_form = p_form.save(commit=False)
     p_form.user = u_user
     p_form.company = company
     p_form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure of this solution, without more info about Company model/db. But based on the experience of moving my projects before, are you sure your Company model on the sever with the new DB contains any objects for your `company=Company.objects.filter(company_name=request.POST["company"]).first()` to return?

It looks like your querying for a company called "demo" in the views.py, to use as the ForeignKey for your profile. Are you sure this is returning an instance of a Company?

Comment: I am using same postgres database on both local and production and yes I am getting company instance on my local system it means I am getting company instance on production as well as I am using same database.